# What if I sell an stock that is going to give an stock dividend after the ex-date but before the payable date

Tags: dividends, ex-dividend-date, stock-dividend

I know that in the case of cash dividends I will get the dividend as long as I bought the stock before the ex-date but what happens in the case of an stock dividend?

Comment: So I if I have 10 stocks and sell them after the ex-date of a 10:11 stock dividend I will have 1 new stock on de payable date?

Comment: That would generally be the case, yes.

Comment: I recently had that happen twice: I received a quarterly DRIP dividend, and it took me a quarter to figure out how to sell a fractional share... By which time I received another DRIP dividend. Sold the second fractional share much faster. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I know that in the case of cash dividends I will get the dividend as long as I bought the stock before the ex-date but what happens in the case of an stock dividend?

This is same as cash dividends. You would receive the additional stock.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what Investopedia says about payouts for ex-dividend stocks:

> A stock trades ex-dividend on or after the ex-dividend date (ex-date). At this point, the person who owns the security on the ex-dividend date will be awarded the payment, regardless of who currently holds the stock. After the ex-date has been declared, the stock will usually drop in price by the amount of the expected dividend.

Read more: Ex-Dividend Definition | Investopedia http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/ex-dividend.asp#ixzz4Nl4J3s4k

I hope this helps.

Good luck!